# Snapshot of the Relation

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I have a table employee which  have attribute such as empid ,empname,emdpadd, phone no). I would like to take the snapshot of the table at every 10 seconds. I want to implement this using a trigger. Any guidance how can I achieve this?

Assume at t=0 contents of my employee relation is

```
empid empname empadd phoneno 
12     Abc     delhi  xxx
13     def     mumbai  yyy
```

so snapshot should be same as above

```
empid empname empadd phoneno 
12     Abc     delhi  xxx
13     def     mumbai  yyy
```

Now suppose if I alter 1 tuple at 11 sec (changing the address of row1 of employee)

```
empid empname empadd phoneno:
12     Abc     jaipur   xxx
13     def     mumbai  yyy
```

so now snapshot should be same as above

```
empid empname empadd phoneno 
12     Abc     jaopur   xxx
13     def     mumbai  yyy
```

All the snapshot at every interval of 10 seconds should be saved (With update value if it happens).

How can I do this with the help of triggers?

Comment: Please describe your **real case**. It looks like  [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @lad2025 please check i have edited the question.

Comment: You still don't tell us **why** you want to do that.

Comment: i am trying to make a project , by implementing the snapshot concept

Comment: imaging your table becomes 2GB big and full scan of it takes longer then 10 seconds - what you do then? enlarge interval or change concept? not to tell that per hour you would produce 720GB barely different snapshots...